# Where do I store uploaded images or files in a mern stack app

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm working on a project. I'm using node and express for the rest api and next js for the front-end.

I have form where users can add new products.

Where should I store the uploaded images?

Should I create a folder `uploads` in the website folder root or upload images in `client/public/assets/img/`?

If I create a folder uploads in root how should I access those images in the front-end?

I know how to upload images or files. I just want to know what is best location to store them

This my project structure

```
Website
--------
  client
  -------
    components
    pages
    public
    styles
    ...
  server
  ------
    config
    controllers
    middlewares
    models
    routes
    utils
    server.js
```

Comment: checkout `cloudinary.com`which I personally like n use :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be create a **Upload** folder in backend directory. When client upload an image you have move that image in **Upload** folder with specific name and that name should save in database.
Please check this one [uploadFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)

Comment: I know how to upload an image or a file. I want to know which would best to store file. you've said I should store them in a folder uploads inside backed. can you explain why? what are benefits of using this approach over the other?

Comment: Because client folder use for frontend, if the size of folder will increase the web site will take too much time to load files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a storage service like `AWS S3` to store files as at some point, your server's storage will be full.

To implement you can use AWS's js SDK with multer and multer s3 uploader to get it working.